# Jasper Server JRDocxExporter

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I downloaded jasper server and want to write custom docx exporter
Does anuone location of bean with this class ? net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.ooxml.JRDocxExporter

I suppose, that there is a chance that jasper server is instantiating JRDocxExporter somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found out the required bean for docx generator.

```
<bean id="reportDocxExporter" class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.action.ReportDocxExporter" parent="baseReportExporter">
    <property name="setResponseContentLength" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

To have custom logic - ovveride this bean